# How can I see the implementations of these methods?

Tags: asp.net-core

In the `Program.cs` of an ASP.NET Core 3.1 app, you can see methods like `CreateHostBuilder()` and `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()` which return an `IHostBuilder` instance, and `Build()` which returns an `IHost` instance, etc.

I wanna take a look at what's happening behind the scenes, "Go to Definition" brings me to the static class `Host` where the methods are only declared without implementation just like things are with abstract classes or interfaces.

Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to look in the [Asp.Net Core repo](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore)

Also, you may use the [Rider IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/), which has a pretty good decompiler out of the box. But, keep in mind that you would probably need to buy\find a license for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just use Go to Definition F12 to see the details definition for the method it will just show the method name and description, it will not show the codes implement.

If you want to see details information, you could find the details inside the asp.net core source codes by using the github's search method.

More details, you could refer to this source [codes](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/f08285d0b6918fbb2b485d97f4e411dc9ea9a94f/src/DefaultBuilder/src/WebHost.cs#L153).

Comment: That's exactly what I expected. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: If you feel my reply has helped you, please mark it as answer, so that other folks who face the same error could find the solution more easily. Thank you.